# Package `foreach` and void function

Tags: r, foreach

I had a quick look at [this vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.pdf) on the `foreach` package used to run jobs in parallel. It looks like a pretty powerful package. I think the foreach function always return something. What if I don't want the function to return anything (a void function)?

Of course, I could just do something like

```
TRASH = foreach(i=1:1000) %dopar% {
   ...
   ...
   NULL
}
```

but it just doesn't look really good. Is there an alternative solution?

Comment: are you looking for `?invisible`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap your function using the `?invisible` function.